# Cauchy's Inequality $|f(z)|\leq k|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function satisfying $|f(z)|\leq k|z|^2$ for some positive constant $k$ and all $z$.

Show that $f(z)=az^2$ for some constant $a$

Attempt: I have proved that $f(z)$ has degree at most 2 using Cauchy's inequality and using the fact that $f(0)=0$

$f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2$ and $f(iz)=ia_1z-a_2z^2$. Using triangle inequality:

$$|f(z)+f(iz)| \leq |f(z)|+|f(iz)|$$

So:

$$|f(z)+f(iz)| \leq |f(z)|+|f(iz)| \leq k|z|^2+k|iz|^2=2k|z|^2$$

But:

$$|f(z)+f(iz)|=|a_1||z||i+1|$$

So:

$$|a_1||z||1+i| \leq 2k|z|^2$$

Now you see (for example consider small real $z$), that the inequality is satisfies if only if $|a_1|=0$.

Comment: I understood this. But there is any other way of approaching this problem, I mean right from the beginning of the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The condition implies that 
$$
{f(z) \over z^2}
$$
is bounded, hence it has a removable singularity at $0$ and therefore is constant?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: near 0 what term of $f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2$ is "in charge"?

EDIT: another idea.

$$|f(z)|\leq k|z|^2$$
implies (Riemann's theorem) that
$$z\longmapsto\frac{a_1z+a_2z^2}{z^2}=\frac{a_1}z+a_2$$
has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "in charge"?

Comment: @prat, greater (in |.|).

Comment: $a_1z$ is in charge

Comment: The inequality is possible if $a_1\ne 0$?