# $f(z) = Kz^2$ if $|f(z)| \leq |z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is entire and satisfies $|f(z)| \leq |z|^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I would like to show that $f(z) = Kz^2$ where $|K| \leq 1$.

My attempt so far:

Since $f$ is entire:
$$f(z) = f(0) + f'(0)z + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}z^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}z^3 + \ldots$$
First observe that from the hypothesis $|f(0)| \leq 0 \implies f(0) = 0$, and so we can omit the constant term in the power series expansion of $f$:
$$f(z) = f'(0)z + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}z^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}z^3 + \ldots$$
Now consider a circle of radius $R$ around $z = 0$. Using Cauchy's inequality we have
$$f^{(n)}(0) \leq \frac{n!\sup f} {R^n} \leq \frac{n!R^2} {R^n}.$$
Thus $f$ must be of the form
$$f(z) = f'(0)z + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}z^2.$$
This is as far as I have got. I need to somehow show that the linear term has coefficient 0 and I also have not used the condition that $|K| \leq 1$ so I know I must be missing something.

I have also looked at [Cauchy's Inequality $|f(z)|\leq k|z|^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952361/cauchys-inequality-fz-leq-kz2) and [Question on application of Liouville's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327360/question-on-application-of-liouvilles-theorem), but I am still unclear on the last part of the proof.

Thanks.

Comment: I would use the Riemann removable singularity theorem in conjuction with Liouville on $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$. This proof is a little less elegant and more work.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Would you mind going through that for pedagogical purposes? That would be much appreciated. I am self teaching this material so I am more focused on the concepts as opposed to elegance at this point of my education.

Comment: You might want to think about whether $|az| \leq |z|^2$ everywhere, so you can say something about the $f'(0)z$ term...

Comment: @EricTowers If $|a| > 1$ then the above holds true only outside a disk of radius $a$ centered at 0, otherwise it's true only within that disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing $f'(0)=0$ is a simple estimate. Suppose $f'(0)\neq 0$. For sufficiently small $|z|$, $|f'(0)z|$ dominates $|\frac{f''(0)}{2}z^2|$, hence
$$|f(z)| \approx |f'(0)||z| \leq K|z|^2,$$
but this is not true!

To make this argument rigorous, one may proceed as follows. Choose small $\delta>0$ such that
$$|z|<\delta \Longrightarrow  \left| \frac{f''(0)}{2}z^2 \right| \leq \frac12 |f'(0)z|.$$
Then, we have
$$|Kz^2| \geq |f(z)| = \left| f'(0)z +\frac{f''(0)}{2} z^2\right|\geq \frac12 |f'(0)z|, \quad |z|<\delta$$
which is contradiction.